# Cómo automatizo la fecha de expedición para un documento?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Quiero generar un documento que muestre la fecha de expedición automáticamente. Conseguí este código

```
$qry=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tblresident r left join tblclearance c on c.residentid = r.id where residentid = '".$_GET['resident']."' and clearanceNo = '".$_GET['clearance']."' ");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
      $bdate = date_create($row['bdate']);
      $date = date_create($row['dateRecorded']);
      echo '
            <p><b>
               CI: <u>'.strtoupper($row['ci']).'</u><br>
               APELLIDO: <u>'.strtoupper($row['lname']).'</u><br>
               PRIMER NOMBRE: <u>'.strtoupper($row['fname']).'</u><br>
               SEGUNDO NOMBRE: <u>'.strtoupper($row['mname']).'</u><br>
               DIRECCION: <u>'.strtoupper($row['formerAddress']).'</u><br>
               LUGAR DE NACIMIENTO: <u>'.strtoupper($row['bplace']).'</u><br>
               TIEMPO EN URBANISMO (AÑOS): <u>'.strtoupper($row['lengthofstay']).'</u><br>
               EDAD: <u>'.strtoupper($row['edad']).'</u><br>
                                   
               ESTADO CIVIL: <u>'.strtoupper($row['civilstatus']).'</u><br>
               NACIONALIDAD: <u>'.strtoupper($row['nationality']).'</u><br>
                                    
             </b></p>
             <p><b>
                                    
               CERTIFICADO EXPEDIDO: <u>'.strtoupper(date_format($date,"F j, o")).'</u><br><br><br><br>
                                    
             </b></p>
            ';
  }
```

Sin embargo no me da la fecha actual del sistema. No tengo mucho conocimiento sobre estas funciones, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo es mostrar una fecha que está registrada en la base de datos y lo estás obteniendo aquí `$date = date_create($row['dateRecorded']);`

Para mostrar la fecha actual en `PHP` puedes usar la función `date()`. Pero antes debes asegurarte que el servidor esté en tu zona horaria o debes configurarla previamente mediante `date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');`.

Aquí encuentras el [listado de las zonas horarias permitidas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    //Setear la zona horaria
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
    //Mostrar la fecha actual
    echo 'CERTIFICADO EXPEDIDO: <u>' . date("Y-m-d h:i:s") . '</u>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

> Y-m-d h:i:s = año-mes-dia horas:minutos:segundos //ejemplo: 2023-06-05 08:33:30

Otros formatos y más información de la [función date, aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Ya entiendo, muchas gracias